# Setting previous data in Grid View

Tags: c#, gridview

i have a grid view that , user will have to type something in the textboxes and wadever the user type will be inserted into the database , i  have this 2 problem or issues whereby , everytime i click the "+" button ( adds news row ) , one of the textbox of the previous row data will be removed .. And the radiobutton selected will be removed as well. Heres is the screenshot what the problem is :

[image]

After clicking the " + " button , it will turn to be like this :

[image]

This is my code behind :

```
 private void AddNewRowToGrid()
    {
        int rowIndex = 0;

        CheckBox chkbox1 = (CheckBox)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[2].FindControl("CheckBox1");
        CheckBox chkbox2 = (CheckBox)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[2].FindControl("CheckBox2");

        if (ViewState["CurrentTable"] != null)
        {
            DataTable dtCurrentTable = (DataTable)ViewState["CurrentTable"];
            DataRow drCurrentRow = null;
            if (dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 1; i <= dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    //extract the TextBox values
                    TextBox box1 = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[1].FindControl("TextBox1");
                    TextBox box2 = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[2].FindControl("TextBox2");
                    TextBox box3 = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[2].FindControl("TextBox3");

                    drCurrentRow = dtCurrentTable.NewRow();


                    dtCurrentTable.Rows[i - 1]["Question"] = box1.Text;       
                    dtCurrentTable.Rows[i - 1]["Hints"] = box3.Text;


                    rowIndex++;
                }
                dtCurrentTable.Rows.Add(drCurrentRow);
                ViewState["CurrentTable"] = dtCurrentTable;

                GridView1.DataSource = dtCurrentTable;
                GridView1.DataBind();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Write("ViewState is null");
        }

        //  Set Previous Data on Postbacks
        SetPreviousData();
    }

     private void SetInitialRow()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        DataRow dr = null;
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Question", typeof(string)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Hints", typeof(string)));

        dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr["Question"] = string.Empty;
        dr["Hints"] = string.Empty;


        dt.Rows.Add(dr);


        //Store the DataTable in ViewState
        ViewState["CurrentTable"] = dt;

        GridView1.DataSource = dt;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }

    private void SetPreviousData()
    {
        int rowIndex = 0;
        if (ViewState["CurrentTable"] != null)
        {
            DataTable dt = (DataTable)ViewState["CurrentTable"];
            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    TextBox box1 = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[1].FindControl("TextBox1");
                    TextBox box2 = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[2].FindControl("TextBox2");
                    TextBox box3 = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[2].FindControl("TextBox3");



                    //Setting previous text to the respective textboxes based on columns.
                    box1.Text = dt.Rows[i]["Question"].ToString();
                    box2.Text = dt.Rows[i]["Hints"].ToString(); 
                    box3.Text = dt.Rows[i]["Hints"].ToString(); 


                    Session["Question1"] = box1.Text;
                    rowIndex++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I can easily do this when only there is one textbox on each columns .. but now there is 2 textboxes on each columns ... because i can only append text to the textboxes based on columns names ... Also , how do i maintain my radiobutton help is appreciated , thanks !

Comment: The problem is that you are saving two textbox values to one datatable column. It would be better to have two columns in data table, one for each textbox. HintsOne, HintsTwo OR use some separator to merge both textboxes values to put into datatable table one column (Hints). Then separate them before displaying into Gridview... its not good so prefer first approach (using two columns)

Comment: yeah i thought of that as an alternative , but i would like to work this way out .. duno if it is possible ..

Comment: One column will always have values for single textbox until unless you merge the values from two textboxes before putting into data column. dt.Rows[i]["Hints"].ToString(); will always return single values (most likely whatever you saved from textbox3. Hence you have options to have two data columns or merge the values before storing into datatable and split the values before putting back into textboxes.

Comment: thanks for the idea ... but can u show me an example please? thx

Comment: Please share code where you put values into datatable. I write you complete workaround, how it would work. At the moment you just sahred where you take values from datatable but not where you store into datatable

Comment: updated . pls tell me if u need more , thanks for the help

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 2):

```
 private void AddNewRowToGrid()
        {
            int rowIndex = 0;

            CheckBox chkbox1 = (CheckBox)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[2].FindControl("CheckBox1");
            CheckBox chkbox2 = (CheckBox)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[2].FindControl("CheckBox2");

            if (ViewState["CurrentTable"] != null)
            {
                DataTable dtCurrentTable = (DataTable)ViewState["CurrentTable"];
                DataRow drCurrentRow = null;
                if (dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    for (int i = 1; i <= dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count; i++)
                    {
                        //extract the TextBox values
                        TextBox box1 = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[1].FindControl("TextBox1");
                        TextBox box2 = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[2].FindControl("TextBox2");
                        TextBox box3 = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[2].FindControl("TextBox3");

                        drCurrentRow = dtCurrentTable.NewRow();


                        dtCurrentTable.Rows[i - 1]["Question"] = box1.Text;         
                        dtCurrentTable.Rows[i - 1]["Hints"] = box2.Text;
                        dtCurrentTable.Rows[i - 1]["Hints1"] = box3.Text;


                        rowIndex++;
                    }
                    dtCurrentTable.Rows.Add(drCurrentRow);
                    ViewState["CurrentTable"] = dtCurrentTable;

                    GridView1.DataSource = dtCurrentTable;
                    GridView1.DataBind();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Response.Write("ViewState is null");
            }

            //  Set Previous Data on Postbacks
            SetPreviousData();
        }

         private void SetInitialRow()
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            DataRow dr = null;
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Question", typeof(string)));
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Hints", typeof(string)));
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Hints1", typeof(string)));

            dr = dt.NewRow();
            dr["Question"] = string.Empty;
            dr["Hints"] = string.Empty;
            dr["Hints1"] = string.Empty;


            dt.Rows.Add(dr);


            //Store the DataTable in ViewState
            ViewState["CurrentTable"] = dt;

            GridView1.DataSource = dt;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }

        private void SetPreviousData()
        {
            int rowIndex = 0;
            if (ViewState["CurrentTable"] != null)
            {
                DataTable dt = (DataTable)ViewState["CurrentTable"];
                if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
                    {
                        TextBox box1 = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[1].FindControl("TextBox1");
                        TextBox box2 = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[2].FindControl("TextBox2");
                        TextBox box3 = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[2].FindControl("TextBox3");



                        //Setting previous text to the respective textboxes based on columns.
                        box1.Text = dt.Rows[i]["Question"].ToString();
                        box2.Text = dt.Rows[i]["Hints"].ToString(); 
                        box3.Text = dt.Rows[i]["Hints1"].ToString(); 


                        Session["Question1"] = box1.Text;
                        rowIndex++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

I just added another column rest of code was already working fine.